# hmvc 404 error in CodeIgniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I have these following lines of code in my project HMVC CodeIgniter 3.0 PHP7

config.php

```
    $config['base_url'] = '';
    $config['index_page'] = '';
    $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

routes.php

```
    $route['default_controller'] = 'service';
    $route['404_override'] = '';
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

the root of my folders are as follows

```
project
| application
| | config
| | | config.php
| | | routes.php
| | modules
| | | service
| | | | models
| | | | | ...
| | | | views
| | | | | ...
| | | | controllers
| | | | | Service.php
|
.htaccess
```

Service.php

```
class Service extends MX_Controller {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    //code       
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
     public function index() {
      //code
      this index function should load by default
     }
}
```

URL on browser : http://localhost/project/

result:

> CodeIgniter error:
>
> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Comment: Controller (Class) name even file name must be started with capital letter

Comment: yes its capital letter in my code

Comment: yes both are same

Comment: @SanhitaSinha you provided code in `Service.php` is totally wrong parentheses

Comment: what is wrong can you plz specify

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/hmvc-an-introduction-and-application--net-11850

Comment: `$route['default_controller'] = 'service/service/index';`  and example `$route['default_controller'] = 'module/controllername/function';`

Comment: Also let you know with new version of HMVC you may need this https://pastebin.com/vNUhJCss

Comment: Also try with index.php like `http://localhost/project/index.php/service/service` if works then you need to change the htaccess make sure you place the .htaccess out side of application folder.

Comment: changed to $route['default_controller'] = 'service/service/index';
it didnot work.
i need service to be loaded when http://localhost/project/ is written at url

Comment: Did you put the core files that came with HMVC correct places.